# How to take call from Sinch from background service in android?

Tags: android, firebase, service, sinch, android-sinch-api

I want to add app to app calling feature in my android app. I am using sinch SDK for that.
I have set up correctly and can receive and accept calls in a very basic manner.

Now I have created a background service so that I can have notification for incoming calls along with playing ringtone and also showing notifications for missed calls if the call is hung up from the caller side.

**PROBLEM** : When I tap the notification it opens another activity which have the UI for incoming calls and two buttons for accepting and rejecting the calls. I am not able to access the call on there. I can neither accept the call nor reject the call.

here is the code for by background service:

```
    private DatabseReferenct ref;
    Uri ring = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    Ringtone r ;

    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {



        ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), ring);

        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!=null)
        {
            dobackgroundworkd(jobParameters);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            r.setLooping(true);
        }

        return true;
    }



    private void dobackgroundworkd(JobParameters jobParameters) {

        notificationManager=NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);


        sinchClient= Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(getApplicationContext())
                .userId(auth)
                .applicationKey(MY_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(MY SECRET)
                .environmentHost("clientapi.sinch.com")
                .build();

        sinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
        sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);
        sinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();

        sinchClient.start();

        sinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new CallClientListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call call) {


                callerName=null;

                                       // JUST TO GET THE NAME OF THE CALLER FROM FIREBASE DATABASE

                ref.child(call.getRemoteUserId()).child("Name").addValueEventListener(new 
                                                                   ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                        {

                                callerName=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                                notificaionChannel1(call);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });




                           // TO LISTEN FOR CALL STATUS

                call.addCallListener(new CallListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCallProgressing(Call call) {

                                giveNotification(call);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCallEstablished(Call call) {
                        r.stop();
                        notificationManager.cancel(INCOMING_CALL_ID);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCallEnded(Call call) {        // TO GIVE THE MISSED CALL NOTIFICATION

                                Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID_1)
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.incoming_call)
                                        .setContentTitle("Missed Call")
                                        .setContentText(callerName + " was calling you")
                                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                        .setAutoCancel(false)
                                        .build();
                                notificationManager.notify(MISSED_CALL, notification);
                            }
                            r.stop();
                            call.hangup();
                            call = null;

                    }


            }
        });

    }



                  ****THIS FUNCTION IS FOR THE MAIN NOTIFICATION OF INCOMING CALLS****

          void giveNotification ( Call call)            {


        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Incoming_call_activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("UID",call.getRemoteUserId());
        intent.putExtra("calltype","incoming");

        PendingIntent =pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID_1)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.incoming_call)
                .setContentTitle("Incoming Call")
                .setContentText(callerName+" is calling you")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .build();

        r.play();

        notificationManager.notify(INCOMING_CALL_ID,notification);

            }
```

And this is the code of other activity Incoming_call_activity.class file:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_call_activity);




                **GETTING THE INTENT VALUES FROM BACKGROUND ACTIVITY**

         uid=getIntent().getStringExtra("UID");
         incall=getIntent().getStringExtra("calltype");



        sinchClient= Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(getApplicationContext())
                .userId(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .applicationKey(MY_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(MY_SECRET)
                .environmentHost("clientapi.sinch.com")
                .build();


        sinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
        sinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        sinchClient.start();

        sinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new SinchCallClientListener());


        takeCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(currentCall!=null)
                    currentCall.answer();               
            }
        });

}

                   **** THESE ARE THE SINCH CALL HANDLERS MENTIONED ABOVE****

 private class SinchCallClientListener implements CallClientListener{

        @Override
        public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call call) {
            if(currentCall==null)
            {
                currentCall=call;
                currentCall.addCallListener(new SinchCallListener());
            }
        }
    }

    private class SinchCallListener implements CallListener {
        //when the call ends for any reason
        @Override
        public void onCallEnded(Call call) {
            //no current call
            currentCall = null;
            //volume buttons go back to controlling ringtone volume
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
        }

        //recipient picks up the call
        @Override
        public void onCallEstablished(Call call) {


            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
        }

        //when call is "ringing"
        @Override
        public void onCallProgressing(Call call) {

        }

        //don't worry about this for now
        @Override
        public void onShouldSendPushNotification(Call call, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {}
    }
```

Comment: You should not start the client on emore time, if you expose and service you should expose the call in that service. Look at our push sample apps in the downloads for some implementation details

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @cjensen . I am learning it all by myself. Thanks for providing the samples.

Comment: Can I pass the Call variable from the service to the other activity? If not then how can I take the call from the service. Please help me here a little bit sir. @cjensen